# AndroidRX - run method in background

Tags: android, android-asynctask, rx-java

I created simple activity with infinity progres bar, and I'am trying to run time consuming method using RxJava to prevent UI thread from blocking, but everytime UI thread is blocked. I think my solution has problem with emitting Observable. Can anyone help me? I'am begginer in RX.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void doSomething(View view) {
    doHeavyStuff()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnNext(new Action1() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object o) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FINISHED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .subscribe();
}

private Observable doHeavyStuff() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 999999999; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        }
    }
    return Observable.just(1);

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your doHeavyStuff() executes computation on calling thread, you just wrap your **result** into Observable.
In order to wrap **computation** into observable you should use *defer*

```
Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<Integer> call() {
        return Observable.just(doHeavyStuff());
    }
});
```

then you can specify threads by *subscribeOn* and *observeOn* methods

Answer (score 36):

With RxJava2 a possible solution is:

#### Version with lambdas:

```
Single.fromCallable(() -> loadInBackground())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe((resultObject) -> { updateUi(resultObject) });
```

#### Version without lambdas:

```
Single.fromCallable(new Callable<Object>() {
    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        return loadInBackground();
    }
})
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(new Consumer<Object>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(Object resultObject) throws Exception {
        updateUi(resultObject);
    }
 });
```

#### Example methods used above:

```
private Object loadInBackground() {
    // some heavy load code
    return resultObject;
}

private void updateUi(Object resultObject) {
    // update your Views here
}
```

Comment: hi @vovahost The result of subscribe is not used ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. If you're are referring to the example, I didn't add more code to make it simple but you would use `myObject`. For example `myObject` can be a user object and you would display it's fields in a Profile screen.

Comment: lint checks for your code shows message --->"The result of subscribe is not used" . I think IDE treats it as potentially unsafe

Comment: You should post your code to pastebin and post here the link. Without actual code it's hard to say.

Comment: can I use void return type for `loadInBackground()` method.. if yes then how i can use it?

Comment: @Fra Red Change it to: `Completable.fromRunnable(() -> loadInBackground())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(() -> { updateUi() });`

Answer (score 11):

According to [docs](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.netflix.rxjava/rxjava-async-util/0.17.5/rx/util/async/operators/OperationFromFunctionals.java#OperationFromFunctionals.fromFunc0%28rx.functions.Func0%29)

Deprecated:
**fromFunc0**
Unnecessary now that Func0 extends Callable. Just call fromCallable(java.util.concurrent.Callable) instead.

So you could make the call in this way:

```
Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {
                return someMethod();
            }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Action1<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Object object) {

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 11):

kotlin use below code to work in background

```
 Single.fromCallable {
                  // method that run in background

          }
           .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
           .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
           .subscribe()
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use [RxJavaAsyncUtil](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaAsyncUtil):

```
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava-async-util:0.21.0'
```

Code:

```
Observable.fromFunc0(() -> doHeavyStuff())
```