# Where to put reused values used for every emission in Observable/ Flowable?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have some expensive operations that only need to be performed once (e.g. load/ download large files, load large ML models, or calculate optimized data structure based on some other data). I want to use this for every value the Observable/ Flowable generates:

The following code works, but it runs `heavyProcessing()` and `heavyProcessing2()` on the caller's thread. In my case, I can't choose what my callers thread (its the `main` thread because I am using WorkManager's RxWorker, which calls createWork from `main`). Therefore, `start` blocks the main thread. How do I get `heavyProcessing` to be performed in the background with RxJava and also available to the subsequent RxJava chain?

```kotlin
fun start(): Observable<Unit> {
    val heavy = heavyProcessing() // the heavy value i want to use everywhere!
    val anotherHeavyObject = heavyProcessing2()
    val items = Observable.fromIterable(listOfHundredsOfItems)
             .map { doSomeWork(it, heavy) }
             .map { doSomeWork(it, anotherHeavyObject) }
}
```

### My attempts has so far not worked:

1. Create a wrapper around the existing function: The issue with this code is the Observable returned by `start()` does not get observed, so the `doSomeWork` doesn't actually get done. I only know this because I put breakpoints in at `doSomeWork`, and it never gets called.

```kotlin
    fun startInBackground(): Single<Unit> {
        return Single.fromCallable {
            start()
        }
    }
```

2. I've been trying to find ways of 'unnesting' the inner `Observable` (inside the `Single`), as that's probably the issue here. The inner `Observable` is not being observed.

This RxJava stuff is very unintuitive even after reading the [guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava)

Comment: Its might be related to "deferred-dependent" https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#deferred-dependent though I have no idea why. The code doesn't make sense but I understand `implicit data dependency between the previous sequence and the new sequence `.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it was related to [Deferred-dependent](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#deferred-dependent). The example in the docs state:

> Sometimes, there is an implicit data dependency between the previous sequence and the new sequence that, for some reason, was not flowing through the "regular channels". One would be inclined to write such continuations as follows:

```kotlin
AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();

Observable.range(1, 10)
  .doOnNext(ignored -> count.incrementAndGet())
  .ignoreElements()
  .andThen(Single.defer(() -> Single.just(count.get())))
  .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

### Actually, all I needed the caller to do is:

```kotlin
Single.defer { start() }.map { doMoreWork() }
```

instead of

```kotlin
start().map { doMoreWork() }
```

Comment: I just realized, the answer to this question can also be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31498847/androidrx-run-method-in-background